# How do I nest multiple HTML elements under one element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am using Javascript/socket.io to display a chat message. I am trying to mirror the structure/classes that already exist in my HTML file:

```
<li>
    <span id="messageUsername">{{message.user}}</span>
    <p id="messageViewContent">{{message.content}}</p>
</li>
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
const li = document.createElement('li');
const spanUser = document.createElement('span');
const p = document.createElement('p');
spanUser.innerHTML = `${data.messageUser}`
spanUser.classList.add("messageUsername")
p.innerHTML = `${data.messageContent}`;
p.classList.add("messageViewContent");
li.innerHTML = p + spanUser;
document.querySelector('#messageLoop').append(li);
```

I also tried the following: `li.innerHTML = p, spanUser;` and `li.append(p)`, neither worked. With my current code, instead of display a message it is displaying: [object HTMLParagraphElement]

What am I doing wrong here? It seems so simple but I just can't seem to get the right syntax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are `data.messageUser` and `data.messageContent`? Are they objects? It would helpful to see what they are before you append them to the HTML. Also, you're using `innerHTML()`, if they're text `innerText()` should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate DOM elements, what you really want is append them to the previously created `li` element.

Remove this `li.innerHTML = p + spanUser;`

And append the elements to `li` element.

```
li.append(spanUser);
li.append(p);
```